# Strong Lucas Test; as soon as any condition is met does it stop?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I am wondering something about the [strong Lucas Pseudoprime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Strong_Lucas_pseudoprimes).

Wikipedia states:

[image: screenshot from wikipedia]
(click for larger picture)

Does the normal test (i.e. the not strong one) still need to be done, where $U_{\delta(n)} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ must still be checked? Or are these conditions for the strong done instead of this?

Also, in the article it says one of the conditions must be met. Does that mean as soon as $U_d \equiv 0 \pmod n$ or **any** $V_{d2^r} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ then the strong part of the test doesn't need to be checked anymore? For example as soon as the congruence holds true for one value of $r$ in $0 \leq r \lt s$ then the rest for other values of r don't need to be checked?

How is $d2^r$ normally calculated? I can think of two ways: doing it in advanced by going through all values or checking each $v_i$ to see if $i$ is of the form $d2^r$

Comment: I only know how the strong fermat test works but it seems to be analogue to the strong lucas test. Isn't the congruence you mentioned in the last part already the (necessary and sufficient) condition we need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the normal test (i.e. the not strong one) still need to be done, where $U_{\delta(n)} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ must still be checked? Or are these conditions for the strong done instead of this?

The article explains this, the strong Lucas test implies the normal one, thus you don't have to do the normal one.

> Does that mean as soon as $U_d \equiv 0 \pmod n$ or **any** $V_{d2^r} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ then the strong part of the test doesn't need to be checked anymore? For example as soon as the congruence holds true for one value of $r$ in $0 \leq r \lt s$ then the rest for other values of r don't need to be checked?

This part *is* the strong test. And yes, as soon as either of those conditions are satisfied for any choice of $r$, you are done and can return that it is a strong pseudoprime.

> How is $d2^r$ normally calculated? I can think of two ways: doing it in advanced by going through all values or checking each $v_i$ to see if $i$ is of the form $d2^r$

You start at $d$ and compute $V_d$. Then you repeatedly double $d$ and use $V_x$ to compute $V_{2x}$, and check after each step. See [this part of the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Implementing_a_Lucas_probable_prime_test).

You compute $n = d 2^r$ by repeatedly dividing $n$ by two until it is no longer divisible by $2$, then you've found $d$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The article says the strong Lucas test implies the normal one, but I didn't get that the actual work of checking $U_{\delta} \equiv 0$ could be skipped. So to confirm you no longer need to calculate $U_{\delta}$ ?

Comment: @northerner Of course you can skip it. Why would you check what you already know? That test is to see if the number is a Lucas pseudoprime, but if you'd execute the stronger test you'd already know that.

Comment: I found an interesting comment on the website https://programmingpraxis.com/2014/02/04/lucas-pseudoprimes/  `I prefer the full extra strong test using the Baillie parameters (A217719) since it has fewer pseudoprimes, runs faster than the standard or strong test, and maintains the same residue class behavior` I have trouble believing this since the extra strong version has an additional version that must be checked, so how could it possibly be faster? PLEASE NOTE: I know some people are sensitive to comments, if you don't respond this won't affect my vote or accepting this as an answer.

Comment: Also the Wikipedia article states "set $P = 1$ and $Q = ( 1 − D ) / 4 $. It is a good idea to check that n has no prime factors in common with P or Q" how does this make sense when P is 1 and Q is possibly negative?

Comment: @northerner Regarding first comment, ask a new question. Regarding the second comment, it's always good to check that, and the described method is just one way of choosing $P, Q$. In this case you do only have to check $Q$. For negative numbers you just ignore the sign.